# ActionListener, List Issue

Tags: java, list, user-interface, actionlistener

I am running into an issue with my program. The objective is to collect input (movie name, media type and the year) and append it to a list when "add movie" is clicked. Then when the "show movies" button is clicked the list will display in the text area. I'm not sure what I am missing or what I've done wrong.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

class MovieDatabase extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    
     //create LinkedList of Movie Objects
    LinkedList<Movie> list = new LinkedList<Movie>(); 
    
    //JPanel for input movie
    private JPanel inputJPanel;
    
    //JLable and JTextField for Movie Name
    private JLabel movieJLabel;
    private JTextField movieJTextField;

    //JLable and JTextField for Media
    private JLabel mediaJLabel;
    private JTextField mediaJTextField; 
    
    //JLable and JTextField for Release Year
    private JLabel yearJLabel;
    private JTextField yearJTextField;
    
    //JButton to add movie to a list
    private JButton addJButton;
    
    //JButton to show movie in text area
    private JLabel showJLabel;
    private JButton showJButton;

    //JTextArea to display movies from list
    private JTextArea showJTextArea;
    private JPanel listJPanel;
    
    //no argument constructor
    public MovieDatabase(){
        createUserInterface();
    }
    
    //create GUI window with components
    private void createUserInterface(){
        //get content pane window and set layout to null - no layout manager
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        //set up input panel
        inputJPanel = new JPanel();
        inputJPanel.setLayout(null);
        inputJPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Input Movie")); //anonymous object
        inputJPanel.setBounds(20,4,260,178);// (x,y,w,h)
        contentPane.add(inputJPanel);
        
        //set up input panel
        showJLabel = new JLabel();
        showJLabel.setLayout(null);
        showJLabel.setText("Movies: "); 
        showJLabel.setBounds(300,0,260,25);// (x,y,w,h)
        contentPane.add(showJLabel);
        
        //set up payment JTextArea here
        showJTextArea = new JTextArea();
        showJTextArea.setBounds(300,30,300,145);// (x,y,w,h)
        showJTextArea.setEditable(false);
        contentPane.add(showJTextArea);
        
        //show movies JButton
        showJButton = new JButton();
        showJButton.setBounds(480,175,110,30);
        showJButton.setText("Show Movies");
        contentPane.add(showJButton);
       
        
        //movie name JLabel
        movieJLabel = new JLabel();
        movieJLabel.setBounds(10,24,100,21);// (x,y,w,h)
        movieJLabel.setText("Movie Name:");
        inputJPanel.add(movieJLabel);
        //movie name JTextField
        movieJTextField = new JTextField();
        movieJTextField.setBounds(104,24,120,21);
        movieJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        inputJPanel.add(movieJTextField);
        
        //media name JLabel
        mediaJLabel = new JLabel();
        mediaJLabel.setBounds(10,54,100,21);// (x,y,w,h)
        mediaJLabel.setText("Media:");
        inputJPanel.add(mediaJLabel);
        //media name JTextField
        mediaJTextField = new JTextField();
        mediaJTextField.setBounds(104,54,120,21);
        mediaJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        inputJPanel.add(mediaJTextField);        
        
        //year name JLabel
        yearJLabel = new JLabel();
        yearJLabel.setBounds(10,84,100,21);// (x,y,w,h)
        yearJLabel.setText("Release Year:");
        inputJPanel.add(yearJLabel);
        //year name JTextField
        yearJTextField = new JTextField();
        yearJTextField.setBounds(104,84,80,21);
        yearJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        inputJPanel.add(yearJTextField);
        
        //add movie JButton
        addJButton = new JButton();
        addJButton.setBounds(92,138,94,24);
        addJButton.setText("Add Movie");
        inputJPanel.add(addJButton);
        
        //set window properties
        setTitle("Movie"); //set title bar
        setSize(625, 250);//window size
        setVisible(true); //display window 
        
        addJButton.addActionListener(this);
        showJButton.addActionListener(this);
        
    }
    
     public void addButtonactionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        String movieName = movieJTextField.getText();
        String media = mediaJTextField.getText();
        int year = Integer.parseInt(yearJTextField.getText());
        //create instance of Movie
        Movie movie = new Movie(movieName, media, year);
        list.add(movie);
        
        movieJTextField.setText("");
        mediaJTextField.setText("");
        yearJTextField.setText("");         
     }
    private void showButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        showJTextArea.setText("");
        String str = String.format("%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", "Year", "Media", "Title");
        showJTextArea.append(str);
        for (Movie movie : list) {
             str = String.format("%-20s%-19s%-22s\n", Integer.toString(movie.year), movie.media, movie.name);
             showJTextArea.append(str);
        }
    }  
         
}

 class Movie{
 String name;
 String media;
 int year;

 public Movie(String n, String m, int y){
 name = n;
 media = m;
 year = y;
 }


public class MovieGUI {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MovieDatabase application = new MovieDatabase();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        
  
        

    }//close and stop application
    
}
 }
```

Comment: The interface for `ActionListener` only has one method to be implemented `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`  - this will be called for both button.  Depending on the `Source` of the `ActionEvent` you should undertake different actions

Comment: `null` layouts suck, take the time to learn how to use the layout managers [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html); You've not implemented the requirements for `ActionListener` (`showButtonActionPerformed` suggests that you're using something like Netbeans form editor). Maybe you should take a look at [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Comment: You might also want to look at [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 2):

`null` layouts are going to come back to haunt you. There is no such thing as "pixel perfect" layouts, there are just to many variables associated with the differences in the way things get rendered between different hardware and OSs to even consider making this choice.

Take the time to learn how to use the layout managers [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

You've not implemented the requirements for `ActionListener` (`showButtonActionPerformed` suggests that you're using something like Netbeans form editor).

Maybe you should take a look at [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

You might also want to look at [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

To my mind, you need to take a slightly different tact and focus on separating the areas of responsibility.  Collecting the movie information has nothing with either storing the results or displaying them, so I'd have those separated into it's own container, so you can more easily manage it.

This leads to the question of, "how do you notify interested parties when a user 'adds' a movie?".  Interestingly, you're somewhat already familiar with the concept.

Essentially, you use a "listener" or, as it's more commonly known, an "observer pattern".  This allows you to notify interested parties that something has happened, in this case, a user has created a new movie.

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EventListener;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new MovieManagerPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Movie {

        String name;
        String media;
        int year;

        public Movie(String n, String m, int y) {
            name = n;
            media = m;
            year = y;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getMedia() {
            return media;
        }

        public int getYear() {
            return year;
        }


    }

    public class MovieManagerPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextArea moviesTextArea;
        private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>(32);

        public MovieManagerPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            moviesTextArea = new JTextArea(20, 40);
            String str = String.format("%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", "Year", "Media", "Title");
            moviesTextArea.append(str);

            MoviePane moviePane = new MoviePane();
            moviePane.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new TitledBorder("Input Movie"), new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4)));
            moviePane.addMovieListener(new MoviePane.MovieListener() {
                @Override
                public void movieWasAdded(MoviePane source, Movie movie) {
                    movies.add(movie);
                    String str = String.format("%-20s%-20s%-20s\n", movie.getYear(), movie.getMedia(), movie.getName());
                    moviesTextArea.append(str);
                }
            });

            add(moviePane, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
            add(moviesTextArea);
        }

    }

    public class MoviePane extends JPanel {

        public static interface MovieListener extends EventListener {

            public void movieWasAdded(MoviePane source, Movie movie);
        }

        //JLable and JTextField for Movie Name
        private JLabel movieJLabel;
        private JTextField movieJTextField;

        //JLable and JTextField for Media
        private JLabel mediaJLabel;
        private JTextField mediaJTextField;

        //JLable and JTextField for Release Year
        private JLabel yearJLabel;
        private JTextField yearJTextField;

        //JButton to add movie to a list
        private JButton addJButton;

        public MoviePane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            movieJLabel = new JLabel("Movie Name:");
            mediaJLabel = new JLabel("Media:");
            yearJLabel = new JLabel("Release Year:");

            movieJTextField = new JTextField(10);
            mediaJTextField = new JTextField(10);
            yearJTextField = new JTextField(10);

            addJButton = new JButton("Add Movie");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = gbc.EAST;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

            add(movieJLabel, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(mediaJLabel, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(yearJLabel, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.anchor = gbc.WEST;

            add(movieJTextField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(mediaJTextField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(yearJTextField, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = gbc.SOUTH;

            add(addJButton, gbc);

            addJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try {
                        // Use a JSpinner or JFornattedTextField to avoid this
                        int year = Integer.parseInt(yearJTextField.getText());
                        Movie movie = new Movie(movieJTextField.getText(), mediaJTextField.getText(), year);
                        fireMovieWasAdded(movie);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MoviePane.this, "Invalid year", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void addMovieListener(MovieListener listener) {
            listenerList.add(MovieListener.class, listener);
        }

        public void removeMovieListener(MovieListener listener) {
            listenerList.remove(MovieListener.class, listener);
        }

        protected void fireMovieWasAdded(Movie movie) {
            MovieListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(MovieListener.class);
            if (listeners.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            for (MovieListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.movieWasAdded(this, movie);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You may also want to take a look at [How to Use Spinners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) and [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for dealing with "non-string" input

Comment: Thank you. I have not learned spinner yet. i see i forgot my get and set methods, and try catch. I see your point with using a grid layout.